# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: redhat, docker, selinux, docker-compose

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
# uname -a
Linux X.Y.Z 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 20 11:34:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -qa | grep ^docker
docker-rhel-push-plugin-1.13.1-96.gitb2f74b2.el7.x86_64
docker-common-1.13.1-96.gitb2f74b2.el7.x86_64
docker-client-1.13.1-96.gitb2f74b2.el7.x86_64
docker-1.13.1-96.gitb2f74b2.el7.x86_64
#
```

My issue:

```
# docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
# 
# echo $DOCKER_HOST
#
```

yet

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
# 
# docker info | head
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
#
```

I'm using standard package (location) that being shipped by Red Hat, however even though `docker` client works without any issue, it won't work with `docker-compose` for whatever reason...

Please advise.

---

possibly SELinux related issue:

```
# docker-compose ps
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
# getenforce 
Enforcing
# setenforce 0
# docker-compose ps
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
#
```

Comment: Where did you get docker-compose?

Comment: @MichaelHampton https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-as-a-container

Comment: Hm, I dunno if that even works at all with RHEL's docker, as it's forked and significantly modified. Please try docker-compose from EPEL.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have 2 similarly configured hosts (same OS), one works without issue and the other host used to work fine too, until recently applied updates. epel's version is just a lot behind latest.

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't be that far behind, but I dunno if the other maintainer has been keeping up. You might poke him on bugzilla.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 1.18.0 (2017-12-15) vs 1.24.0 (2019-03-28)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of exactly how far behind it is. I looked before I wrote that comment. Again, you'll have to yell at carlwgeorge about that. I don't know why he hasn't updated it.

Comment: Now you seen to have an SELinux issue. You need to look at the audit log.

Comment: @alexus did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @fuzzi yeah, don't use docker-compose container version, use OS version instead or disable selinux